# How to install antlr3 python module on Ubuntu?

Tags: python

If you are getting "Import error: No module named antlr3" while running python application. For example, KeyboardLayoutEditor, Django apps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sudo apt-get install python-setuptools
pip install http://www.antlr3.org/download/Python/antlr_python_runtime-3.1.2.tar.gz
wget http://www.antlr3.org/download/antlr-3.1.2.jar
java -classpath "antlr-3.1.2.jar" org.antlr.Tool *.g
```

Comment: it gives error(7):  `cannot find or open file: *.g`

Comment: I receive the same error than Hector, in this line:

 java -classpath "antlr-3.1.2.jar" org.antlr.Tool *.g

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't remember what was that `*.g` for, what happens if you delete it?